# Number theory sequence question

Tags: number-theory

I have a question on divisiblity of numbers I provided below.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can approach this question? I think it may involve the prime factorization.

Comment: You're right about prime factorization being useful.  I reccomend starting from $360^9$.  If $a^3$ divides that what could $a$ be.  The keep on working back.

Comment: I do not make any progress

Comment: For example, the largest $a$ can be is $360^3$.  In fact, $a$ can be any factor of $360^3$.  How many is that?  For each one, you need to figure out how many choices there are for $b,c$.  There will be the same number of choices (why?).

Comment: Side comment: Why did you delete your Fibonacci question? I'd like to reopen it (I have a way to a solution, I believe), but I don't want to do that if you have a pertinent reason for not wanting it reopened.

Answer (score 0):

It's very weirdly written but it is saying is find all possible sets of numbers $\{a,b,a^2, c, a^3, 360^9\}$  So that each term divides the next.

Hint:  The only possible prime divisors of any of the terms are $2,3$ and $5$ and each of the terms must be of the form $2^{j}3^{k}5^{m}$ where $0 \le j \le 27; 0 \le k \le 18; 0 \le m \le 9$.  ... and each term divides the next.

Play wit it first.  Patterns should start to appear.  What's the smallest $a$ can be?  What's the largest?  etc.

If $a = 2^g3^i5^k$ then $b = 2^{g'}3^{h'}5^{i'}; c= 3^{\overline g}3^{\overline h}5^{\overline i}$ and $g \le g' \le 2g \le \overline g \le 3g \le 27$ and $h \le h' \le 2h \le \overline h \le 3h \le 18$ and $i \le i' \le 2i \le \overline i \le 3i \le 9$.

So $g$ can be any $0... 9$  and $h$ can be any $0... 6$ and $i$ can be any $0...3$  For each choice there are only so many choices for the $s'$ and the $\overline s$.

Comment: What did *I* get as an answer?  I haven't done it!